# Help with understanding proof of theorem towards Erdos-Stone theorem

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The Theorem is

> Let $r \geq 1$ be an integer and let $\epsilon > 0$.
>
> Then there is an integer $n_0 = n_0(r_1\epsilon)$ such that if $|G| = n \geq n_0$ and $$\delta (G) \geq \left( 1-\frac{1}{r} +\epsilon \right)n,$$ then $ K_{r+1}(t) \subset G$, where $$t \geq \frac{\epsilon\text{log}(n)}{2^{r-1}(r-1)!}.$$

I have taken this statement of the theorem from *Modern Graph Theory* by Bollobas, from which I am also trying to understand the proof. I have referred to other lecture notes that include the proof here:

1. [Notes on extremal graph theory](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/III_M/extremal_graph_theory_trim.pdf)
2. [General Graph Theory](http://www.pancratz.org/notes/Graphs.pdf)

However, I am stuck right at the beginning. (Perhaps I will get stuck again!)

All sources use an inductive proof on $r$. I will go by the proof in Bollobas.

The case for $r=1$ is related to the Zarankiewicz problem of finding the maximum size of an $n \times n$ bipartite graph not containing $K_{t,t}$, and has been proved already. There is also a weaker but sufficient-for-the-purposes demonstration.

Given the $r=1$ case, take $r\geq 2$ and let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and minimal degree at least $(1-\frac{1}{r} +\epsilon)n$. Note that $0<\epsilon<1/r$.

**Since $\delta(G) > (1-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r(r-1)})n$**, by the induction hypothesis $G$ contains a $K_r(T)=K$, say, with $|T|=[d_r \log(n)]$.

I do not understand the first part of that statement. Why is $\delta(G) > (1-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r(r-1)})n$? I do not see anything that has been said which implies this to be the case? Since we only have $\epsilon >0$, then strictly speaking we could just have $0$ here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typo. The corrected argument is that since
$$
   \delta(G) \ge \left(1 - \frac1r\right)n = \left(1 - \color{red}{\frac1{r-1}} + \frac1{r(r-1)}\right)n
$$
we have $\delta(G) \ge \left(1 - \frac1{r-1} + \epsilon'\right)n$ for $\epsilon'= \frac1{r(r-1)}$. So we can, by induction, apply the $r-1$ case of this theorem to conclude that $G$ contains a $K_{r}(T)$, where 
$$
    T \ge \frac{\epsilon'\log n}{2^{r-2}(r-2)!} = \frac{\frac1{r(r-1)} \log n}{2^{r-2} (r-2)!} = \frac{\log n}{2^{r-2} r!}.
$$
This expression is rewritten as $d_r \log n$, where $d_r = \frac{2^{2-r}}{r!}$, in the next step.